# Shifting focus to a new popup window that has a null ID and name

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I apologize if this question is redundant - I've seen a number of similar posts on this and other sites but none of them presented a solution that helped me.

I am using Selenium IDE to record a script that clicks a link (which opens a new window with a .shtml extension). I then need to switch focus to the new window and hit the save button to download a PDF.

I don't understand exactly how this works, but the url of the popup window is some generic url (https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/datawarehouse/ConsolidatedEndOfDayReportPDF.shtml) that hosts whatever report you generate on the previous page (https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/ReportCenter.shtml#report/142). If you try an openWindow command on the new URL it won't generate the report, you must open it through a link on the first page.

I want to refocus selenium to the new popup through selectWindow or selectPopup, but the issue is that the popup has no name, ID or title. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to avoid this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried this out myself, but you could use this to find the window names and switch to it.

```
<tr>
<td>storeAllWindowNames</td>
<td>names</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${names}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>.
<tr>
<td>selectWindow</td>
<td><the name you find out></td>
<td></td>
</tr>.
```

You can try with storeAllWindowIds,storeAllWindowTitles. These three methods should return an array of windowids, something like this `, bJHBGug2u8`

Comment: I tried running the text you suggested, but the echoed list does not include any identifier for the new popup. The original window that I open in my script has a title but not a name or ID (so of the three lists, only "title" has any values. This indicates to me that either the popup window doesnt possess a title, ID or name, or that the program is not recognizing it at all. Is there any way to check the number of windows that Selenium has identified?

Comment: What output do you see?

Comment: The echoed lists of titles displays just the one value of the original window, and the echoed lists of names and IDs are both empty